# Conflict between Smoothscroll.js and Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Smoothscroll.js (not using GEM -- see link to code below) on my welcome page so that users can navigate to the appropriate section of the Welcome webpage via fixed Bootstrap Navbar menu selections. On a separate page I'm using a Bootstrap Carousel to allow the user to view and individual portfolio item (show page).

This allows the user to click on the Navbar "Portfolio" menu selection on the Welcome page to smooth scroll to the Portfolio section of the welcome page. The user can then click on a specific Portfolio item on the Welcome page and this will take them to the show page for that specific portfolio item where they can see multiple images for that portfolio item via a Bootstrap Carousel.

The problem is that if I include the Smoothscroll logic within the scope of the `$(document).ready ()` in my app/assets/javascripts/jet.js file (see below) the prev/next controls on the BootStrap Carousel on the show page are non-repsonsive to user clicks.

If I edit the jet.js file and put the Smoothscroll logic outside of the scope of the `$(document).ready ()` function and save those changes and then load my website. Everything works perfectly. The Smoothscroll works as expected on the Welcome page and the prev/next controls work perfectly on the Portfolio show page. I can navigate freely between the two pages (welcome and portfolio show page) and everything continues to work. However, if I reload the webpage and attempt to select a the Navbar selection on the Welcome page to smoothscroll to any section on the Welcome page I get a routing error (e.g.,No route matches [GET] "/index.html").

FYI...my dev environment is:

- Rails 4.2.1
- Using all the latest versions of jQuery(v2.1.3), Bootstrap(v3.3.5)
- Using ([Smoothscroll.js logic](http://www.billerickson.net/code/smooth-scrolling-anchor-links/) ) see jet.js file below
- Ruby v2.1.5
- Turbolinks is disabled (removed from GEMfile and removed other refs)

So I have two related questions:

1) Any idea why the Smoothscroll.js seems to be blocking the prev/next controls from working correctly when Smoothscroll is included in the scope of the $(document).ready() function?

2) I'm wondering why everything seems to work fine when I make the changes (i.e., place smoothscroll.js logic outside of $(document).ready scope) and then load the page with those changes but yet when I reload the web page a second time I get the routing error. It's as if smoothscroll locations are cached on the first load but not across the second load (as noted above)?

For reference here is jet.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Pretty photo script
$("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        theme: 'light_square',
        social_tools: false,
        hook: 'data-rel'
});


$(".truncateIt").dotdotdot({
        // configuration goes here
        /*  The text to add as ellipsis. */
    ellipsis    : '... ',

    /*  How to cut off the text/html: 'word'/'letter'/'children' */
    wrap        : 'word',

    /*  Wrap-option fallback to 'letter' for long words */
    fallbackToLetter: true,

    /*  jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
    after       : 'a.next',

    /*  Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
    watch       : false,

    /*  Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
    height      : 60,

    /*  Deviation for the height-option. */
    tolerance   : 0,

    /*  Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
        receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
    callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {},

    lastCharacter   : {

        /*  Remove these characters from the end of the truncated text. */
        remove      : [ ' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ],

        /*  Don't add an ellipsis if this array contains
            the last character of the truncated text. */
        noEllipsis  : []
    }
});



// WOW Reveals CSS animation as you scroll down a page.
// Link and activate WOW.js
new WOW().init();

$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});

$('#carousel-generic-example').carousel({
        interval:2000,
        pause: "false"
});
$('#playButton').click(function () {
        $('#carousel-generic-example').carousel('cycle');
});
$('#pauseButton').click(function () {
        $('#carousel-generic-example').carousel('pause');
});

}); // /document.ready()

function scroll_to(clicked_link, nav_height) {
    var element_class = clicked_link.attr('href').replace('#', '.');
    var scroll_to = 0;
    if(element_class != '.top-content') {
        element_class += '-container';
        scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - nav_height;
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_to}, 1000);
    }
}

// Scroll location for buttons on banner page
$('a.scroll-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scroll_to($(this), $('nav').outerHeight());
});

// Smooth Scrolling for anchor links: http://www.billerickson.net/code/smooth-scrolling-anchor-links/
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
          || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
             if (target.length) {
               $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
          }
      }
  });

// }); // /document.ready()


    $(".cnbox").each(function () {
        var nheight = $(this).find(".nbox").height();
        $(this).find(".cbox").css("height", nheight + 50);
    });



var caroufredsel = function () {
        $('#caroufredsel-portfolio-container').carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            scroll: 1,
            circular: false,
            infinite: false,
            items: {
                    visible: {
                            min: 1,
                            max: 3
                    }
            },
            prev: '#portfolio-prev',
            next: '#portfolio-next',
            auto: {
                    play: false
            }
    });


    $('#caroufredsel-blog-posts-container').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        scroll: 1,
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        items: {
            visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 3
                }
        },
        prev: '#blog-posts-prev',
        next: '#blog-posts-next',
        auto: {
                play: false
        }
    });
};


// Isotope Portfolio
var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
var $blogcontainer = $('.posts-wrap');
var $filter = $('.portfolio-filter');

$(window).load(function () {
        // Bootstrap Carousel -- Tried each of the following lines but neither of them helped
        // jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
        // jQuery('#carousel-generic-example').carousel();

        caroufredsel();
        // Initialize Isotope
        $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-item-wrapper'
        });

        $blogcontainer.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.article-wrap'
        });

        $('.portfolio-filter a').click(function () {
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
                return false;
        });
        $filter.find('a').click(function () {
                $filter.find('a').parent().removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });


    $(window).smartresize(function () {
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
        $blogcontainer.isotope('reLayout');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        caroufredsel();
    });

});
```

FYI, here is my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but I found JS files (jss-script.js and jss-script.min.js) in plugins folder, so I changed HTML selector to only one div by ID and every `<a>` with `href="#"` in it. Change values in both files.

```js
/****************************************************
 *                                                  *
 *      JUMP TO ANCHOR LINK SCRIPT START            *
 *                                                  *
 ****************************************************/
 /*SSB-CONTAINER WAS MY SIDE PANEL MENU*/
  $('#ssb-container a[href*="#"]').click(function() 
  {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) 
    {
      
      var target = $(this.hash),
      headerHeight = $(".primary-header").height() + 5; // Get fixed header height
            
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              
      if (target.length) 
      {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, scrollSpeed, scrollStyle );
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

And it actually started work!

Answer (score 0):

I switched gears and used the following solution. [Smoothscroll solution](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/). It worked great and was much easier than what I was trying to do.

I'm still puzzled as to what the conflict was in my original solution. It makes me think that I don't understand some aspect of how this all works.

So please feel free to add your comments or a proposed solution if you have an ideas or theories.